# Dialogflow V2 Messenger Integration with Multiple Messages

Tags: facebook-messenger-bot, dialogflow-es

I am trying to send to multiple messages within one Webhook call to Dialogflow, which shall be passed to Messenger. Right now my Webhook responds with a malfunctioning JSON body:

```
{
    'fulfillmentText': "Text",
    'fulfillmentMessages': [{
        "platform": "facebook",
        "text": [{
            "text": "Text"
        }]
    }],
    'source': "facebook"
}
```

When I test the Webhook via Messenger I see the *is typing* symbol, but never receive the *Text* message. While testing the same Webhook from the Dialogflow Console I get

> Webhook execution successful

returned. I guess I am missing some JSON fields to tell Dialogflow in which format it has to send the JSON two the Messenger API. Anybody having any clues on how to solve this issue?

---

**Edit:**
My latest not working trial...

```
{
  "fulfillmentText": "Hola!",
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Title: this is a title"
        ]
      },
      "platform": "FACEBOOK"
    },
    {
      "text": {
        "text": [
          "Title: this is a title"
        ]
      },
      "platform": "FACEBOOK"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mailed the Dialogflow support about this issue and it turns out that it is currently not possible to send multiple messages from a webhook.

> Hi,
>
> At this point, it's not possible to send sequential messages directly
>   from webhook. However, if you are using one of our one-click
>   integrations that support rich messages, you can invoke intents in
>   which multiple messages are defined from webhook through an event as
>   described at
>   https://dialogflow.com/docs/events#invoking_event_from_webhook.
>
> Let me know if you have any questions.
>
> Regards,  Ankita from Dialogflow

Comment: If you ever get a response back when multiple messages can be sent, do update your post and let me know :)

Comment: Has this changed? I think we still can't send multiple messages...

Answer (score 4):

If you're only sending text you only need to provide a string to the `fulfillmentText` and don't have to provide the `fulfillmentMessages` attribute.

If you do provide a `fulfillmentMessages` attribute with the target platform Dialogflow will send your payload to Facebook.  In this case, where the payload is invalid, no message will actually be surfaced in Facebook.  remove the `fulfillmentMessages` attribute of the response JSON and your bot should respond.

If you'd like to add a card to your response you can send the following response:

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "platform": "FACEBOOK",
      "card": {
        "title": "Title: this is a title",
        "subtitle": "This is an subtitle.  Text can include unicode characters including emoji .",
        "imageUri": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "This is a button",
            "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

EDIT: If you want to send multiple messages you can do so by sending a response like this (this JSON will send two identical cards but you can change the message type (card/text/etc) based on [this documentation](https://dialogflow.com/docs/reference/api-v2/rest/v2beta1/projects.agent.intents#Message)):

```
{
  "fulfillmentMessages": [
    {
      "platform": "FACEBOOK",
      "card": {
        "title": "Title: this is a title",
        "subtitle": "This is an subtitle.  Text can include unicode characters including emoji .",
        "imageUri": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "This is a button",
            "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "platform": "FACEBOOK",
      "card": {
        "title": "Title: this is a title",
        "subtitle": "This is an subtitle.  Text can include unicode characters including emoji .",
        "imageUri": "https://developers.google.com/actions/images/badges/XPM_BADGING_GoogleAssistant_VER.png",
        "buttons": [
          {
            "text": "This is a button",
            "postback": "https://assistant.google.com/"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Yes that is what I’m doing right now. But I want to send multiple messages, which I can also do within the dialogflow console while adding text responses.

Comment: Actually your edit represents exactly what I am doing! Instead of using a Card I am using a text object, but Dialogflow does not respond. I posted my doing as an edit. Could you check if you see any errors? If not I am pretty sure the fault is on Dialogflows side!